# What to do with unused familiars?

Tags: blood-brothers

So I have been playing *Blood Brothers* for a few days now, and have racked up a good few familiars in storage. I currently have about 40, and as there is a maximum storage space for 50 I want to start cleaning these up a bit.

For the most part I have been evolving my familiar so I can complete the "Collection", so a lot of these are currently at their maximum evolution, and I just cannot see myself using them in battle. So time to get rid of some.

From what I can tell, there are generally two options I have:

1. I can cash them in for gold
2. I can use them to boost the skills of my main characters

The problem is I don't know which is the best option.

Currently, I have over 300K in gold coins, and from what I can tell, this kind of money is easier to get hold of then spend. So the first question is: Is there anything for me to save up for? or is this kind of money purely for evolving and skill improvement?

With option 2 in mind, most of the familiars (more so the ones I want to get rid of) offer relatively little skill XP for my main characters, but naturally every little counts. One question here might be: is it worth leveling-up a weak familiar before using them for skill improvements? do the higher levels generally make much difference?

I know there is a few "sub-questions" in all that, but the ultimate question is:

**What is more beneficial in the long run? Selling familiars for gold, or using them for skill upgrades?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the rarity of the familiar and your bank account actually. A level one COMMON familiar is worth 9 skill points, a level one UNCOMMON familiar is worth 45 skill points, a level one RARE familiar is worth 90 skill points. And I have a level one EPIC Familiar (4 star familiar) and its worth 1000 skill points. An exception to this is the familiar known as a "SHADE" its basically an offering that gives you 100 skill points (they generally given in events and PVP battles). One thing to note is if you level up your familiar, its skill points will increase. I have two rare familiars of the same type, one is on level 1 the other on level 12. The level 12 familiar is worth 115 skill points while the level one is just 90.

From the my knowledge if you max out a familiar that can go to level 70 or 99 as opposed to 40 they are generally worth more money. Also their rarity and number of times they have evolved determines their value as well. Money becomes essential because the more you level up your familiar's skill points or evolve them, the more expensive it gets. In my opinion sell your COMMON and UNCOMMON Familiars as their worth in skill points becomes meaningless in the long run. Use "SHADES" or RARE familiars you don't want; to upgrade your familiar's skill points because they will help out more in the long run. Be cautious of discarding some RARE familiars though. Some of them are fairly good to keep and some of them can evolve to EPIC familiars. A few UNCOMMON can also become EPIC so keep an eye out for those as well.

There comes a time though, where you have too much money (like 4+ million in my case). In this case might as well use COMMON and UNCOMMON familiars as skill points as well, since money won't be an issue anymore. So if you are able to keep your bank above 300k, its just best to use COMMON and UNCOMMON familiars as skill points as well.

Comment: Thanks for that! Some really great information there. Will definitely keep an eye out for the UC > E familiars. I tend to aim to fully evolve any familiars I have to the max before I think about getting rib of them anyway, so should be ok to spot them.

Comment: Do you happen to know any Uncommon that can evolve to Epic?

Answer (score 0):

There is a third option. Selling your rare or epic familiars in the Bazaar. You can also trade them for other familiars you may want more of. Most 1 star rares (a rare that evolves into epic at 3 stars) will sell for 1 or more ability crystals or even mandrake or horns, which replenish energy or moral instantly.

Check what others are selling the same familiars for and slightly under bid them for quicker success. The common and uncommon can be used however you see fit, they give you almost nothing but them at the graveyard anyway and you can always use bloodmeals to try for more.

Shades and rare sanguine shades can only be used for skill points. I've been a freeloading player for about 5 months now and I have an 10 man, all epic crew of optimally evolved familiars (8 of the same 1 star rares leveled up and combined to create a 4 star epic, or 2 single star epics to make a 2 star epic).